# Fedora VM: how to reset forgotten root password?

Tags: fedora

I have an Oracle VirtualBox VM, with FedoraClient 21 64-bit installed. I cannot remember the root password. As soon as I start up Fedora, I see two options of Fedora: "Client" and "Rescue". Both all start up and leaving me at `localhost login`.

Is there a way to reset the root or local login password before it reaches to the `localhost login` prompt?

Comment: Can you mount your VM's file system on your local system? Then you could edit the root password, see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1655265 for possible steps.

Answer (score 1):

> #### [Reset Password Using a Fedora CD/DVD](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_reset_a_root_password):
>
> > Usage cases
> > *This method should work to reset the root password if the boot loader is password protected.  Or if you have a Fedora 19 (or newer) installation where booting to the rescue mode (which now invokes /sbin/sulogin) will ask you for the root password to proceed.*
>
> **Using any of the Fedora Live Media**
>
> - Boot the Live installation media
> - After it finishes booting and starts the live session, open a terminal and switch to root (using `su`, it won't ask for a password)
> - Create a directory where you can mount the filesystem of your installation:
>   `mkdir /mnt/sysimage`
> - Mount the filesystem of your installation (/dev/sda1 is just an example, be sure to fill in the actual device node of your installation root / partition):
>   `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sysimage`
> - chroot to your installation:
>   `chroot /mnt/sysimage/`
> - Change the root password:
>   `passwd`
> - Exit from the chroot:
>   `exit`
>
> That's it, simply reboot your system and then boot the installation from the HDD as usual.