# Can't log in after fresh install of Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot, login, password

I installed `Windows 10 Pro` on my old `ThinkPad R60` and shrank the `NTFS` partition to `50%` to make space for a dual boot Linux installation. Then I installed `Linux Mint Debian Edition 3`, creating separate `EXT4` root and home partitions with GParted in the process, and having `Grub2` installed into `/dev/sda1` which is the boot partition for both OS. After installation, I booted into the new Linux and found that I cannot log in ("Invalid password, please try again"). I'm positive that I typed in the credentials correctly, I also reinstalled Linux twice using different credentials, but the problem persists. What might be the issue here?

Comment: Are you able to boot into single user mode, and check accounts and passwords?

Comment: Firstly, ensure that it's not a num- or capslock issue. Have you tried logging in on a tty instead of a graphical greeter? You can usually get there by pressing `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Fx`, `x` being a number from 1 to 12; it depends on your setup which ones are designated, but you usually can easily find one by trying. There, you can test your login against the login shell. Just enter the username and press enter, then the password and enter.

Comment: Could it happen that it swaps between your native and English keyboard settings? Just try to type you PW as the user name and see if there are any oddities. Otherwise try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191524/fedora-vm-how-to-reset-forgotten-root-password/191544#191544) - it's similar for `LMDE` and also applies to use-cases outside a VM.

Comment: @RudiC: I looked up `Single User Mode` and tried to boot into it following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub), but I get the error message _"Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked. See sulogin(8) man page for more details."_ - @rudib, Fiximan: I verified the keyboard settings and also tried different credentials after reinstalling `LMDE` several times. Also tried `tty1-tty6` with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

After entering really "dumb" credentials during installation (e.g. "a" for username, password), I'm able to log in. For some reason, `LMDE 3` seems to have an issue with "complex" credentials. Specifically, numerals as username seem to create problems, even though they are accepted initially.

Comment: Please note the discussion on this topic [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287077/why-cant-linux-usernames-begin-with-numbers). This is not LMDE-specific, yet would be better to be declined in the first place.